# Solve $\dfrac{|x|}{|x+2|}<2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Got it.

$$\dfrac{|x|}{|x+2|}<2$$
$$|x|<2|x+2|$$
$$|x|<2x+4$$
$$-x<2x+4<x$$
$$-2x-x<4<x-2x$$
$$-3x<4<-x$$
$$x>\dfrac{-4}{3},x<-4$$
$$(-4,-\infty)\cup(\dfrac{-4}{3},\infty)$$

Comment: Multiplying across the inequality by $x + 2$ is not valid, since the sign of that term is unknown a priori; I'm also not sure where the absolute value bars went.

Comment: An elementary attack on your problem considers $x \leq -2$, then $-2 \leq x \leq 0$, then $0 \leq x$.  Since in each of these regions, you know with which sign to replace the absolute values.

Comment: Redid the question differently but I find myself in the same situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In yor second line, you multiplied both sides by $x+2$, which is negative when $x<-4$. This changes the sign of the inequality.

A more productive way to solve absolute value equations of this sort is to translate it into an equivalent pair of inequalities:

$$|u|<a\implies -a<u<a.$$

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As $\displaystyle\frac{|x|}{|x+2|}=\left|\frac x{x+2}\right|,$

we have  $\displaystyle\left|\frac x{x+2}\right|<2$

For real $\displaystyle x,-2<\frac x{x+2}<2$

If $\displaystyle x+2=0\iff x=-2,\frac x{x+2}=-\infty$

Assuming $x+2\ne0,$

$$\frac x{x+2}<2\iff \frac x{x+2}-2<0\iff-\frac{x+4}{x+2}<0\iff\frac{x+4}{x+2}>0$$

Multiplying  by $\displaystyle(x+2)^2>0, \iff(x+4)(x+2)>0 $

Now if $(x-a)(x-b)>0, (a<b)$ either $x<a$ or $x>b$

Similarly for $$-2<\frac x{x+2}\iff \frac x{x+2}+2>0\iff$$